# Prove that the circumference of a circle is $25\pi$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, pi, polygons

A regular hexagon inscribed in a circle has an area of $$54*3^\frac{1}{3} \text{sq.in}$$
Prove that the circumference of a circle is $$25\pi$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222325/relationship-between-the-sides-of-inscribed-polygons

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The area of a regular $n $-gon inscribed in a circle of radius $R$ is:
$$
A_n=\frac n2 R^2\sin\frac{2\pi}n.
$$
Can you take it from here?

> Warning: the answer will appear to be different from $25\pi$ (in), since the latter value is wrong.

Comment: Could you please prove this?

Comment: @JERRY_XLII http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonregularareaderive.html